# PHP - How to access database config if values are embedded in an array of another file?

Tags: php

How can I access database, host, password and username values if they are embedded in an array of another file? In Sample.php I'm trying to reuse the mentioned values from Configuration.php. How to do so? Unfortunately I can't change Configuration.php.

Configuration.php

```
<?php
return [
    ...
    'DB' => [
        'database' => 'mydatabase',
        'host' => 'myhost',
        'password' => 'mypassword',
        'port' => '',
        'username' => 'myusername',
    ],
    ...
];
```

Sample.php

```
<?php

require('../Configuration.php');

$mysqli = new MySQLi($server,$user,$password,$database);

...
```

Comment: Just get array from file `$arr = include('../Configuration.php');`

Comment: The linked duplicate doesn't explain this, but the `return` means you should store the result in a variable like `$config = include('../Configuration.php');` and then you can read `$config['DB']['host']`

Comment: @jay-blanchard it is not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: Yes it is @axiac. The OP wishes to take an array and separate it into variables for his connection string. If not exact, we can add others.

Comment: @JayBlanchard have you even read the code of both questions? It is a duplicate, I agree, but not of the question you suggested.

Comment: I have read both. I'll add some more dupes.

Comment: Thanks for the help and links. I got it working. Should I delete the post since it's a duplicate?